# Get a portion of information from Laravel Collection, based on offset and limit

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have problems with getting a specific portion of data from Laravel Collection. In my app, I have the following relation between User and Topic:

**User.php model**

```
public function topics() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Topic', 'stdr_user_topics', 'user_id', 'topic_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Topic.php model**

```
public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'stdr_user_topics','topic_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Based on the ralation I'm trying to get a specific portion of topics that belong to an authenticated user:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // Get topics for authenticated user
    $userTopics = Auth::user()->topics;
    if (count($userTopics)) {
        $result = $userTopics
                    ->where('name', '!=', '')
                     ->sortByDesc('followers')
                     ->skip($offset)
                     ->take($limit);
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
}
```

The code above should take the portion of information about user topics, based on `$offset` and `$limit`. However, when ran, it throws this:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::skip()

What is the proper way to achieve what I want for a Collection like above? I'm using Laravel 5.

Comment: See API http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html

Comment: Thanks, I've been there already. I tried using `slice` and `splice`, but the result always came out `false`. Probably some detail in syntax I missed.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you move this clauses you are using inside of `if` statement above like:

```
$userTopics = Auth::user()->topics()->where('name', '!=', '')
                 ->sortByDesc('followers')
                 ->skip($offset)
                 ->take($limit)
                 ->get();
if ($userTopics->count()){
    $result = $userTopics;   
} else {
    $result = false;
}
```

Comment: This is a valid answer. Just keep in mind that by doing it your way, the `$userTopics` is no longer a Collection, but a Builder object. The initial post is about doing this for Collection, though.

Comment: You can even shorthand it: $result = $userTopics->count() ? $userTopics : false;

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you used Constraining Eager Loads ?

Maybe you can do something like

```
Auth::user()->with(['topics' => function($query) use ($limit, $offset) {

    $query->where('name', '!=', '');
    $query->sortByDesc('followers');
    $query->skip($offset);
    $query->take($limit);
}])
```

Please read here for more info: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Good luck!